# Why are the found matches of findall and finditer different?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have made a regex with the `findall` and `finditer` methods, but they are different.
I need `finditer` to find matches like `findall`, and also need to know the span/indexes.

```
import re

string='This is my string.'

letters='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzабвгґдеєжзиіїйклмнопрстуфхцчшщьюяыъэё'
letters+=letters.upper()+'\-\''

print(re.findall(rf'([{letters}]+?)(?:[^{letters}]|$)',string))
print(list(re.finditer(rf'([{letters}]+?)(?:[^{letters}]|$)',string)))

Output:
['This', 'is', 'my', 'string']
[<re.Match object; span=(0, 5), match='This '>, <re.Match object; span=(5, 8), match='is '>, <re.Match object; span=(8, 11), match='my '>, <re.Match object; span=(11, 17), match='string'>]
```

Comment: `[m.group(1) for m in re.finditer(rf'([{letters}]+?)[^{letters}]',string)]` or `[m.group() for m in re.finditer(rf'[{letters}]+?(?=[^{letters}])',string)]`

Comment: `findall` only returns the content of your capture groups. That is documented. If you're only interested in the captured text, you'll have to access the content of the first capture group with `finditer`.

Comment: And how I get the span of the group?

Comment: I need the indexes

Comment: The duplicate mentioned does not address `finditer`... this is not a duplicate.

Comment: Is there an expression that says "find element but not include in the match"?

Comment: `indexes = [(m.start(), m.end()) for m in re.finditer(rf'[{letters}]+?(?=[^{letters}])',string)]`